# How to say that something is no longer in a bag

Tags: phrasal-verbs

For instance, during walking I decided to take some rest for a while, sit down to a bench and **here_probably_should_be_the appropriate_phrassal_verb** a bottle of water out of the bag to drink.

Help me to choose the phrasal.

Comment: The closest you could get for your exact "nuance" might be ***unpacked*** or ***extracted***, but in practice native speakers probably wouldn't bother - they'd just use ***took*** (or even ***got***).

Comment: How about just "pulled"?

Answer (score 2):

You would normally use pulled or took.